# Bxslider doesn't support easing in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, bxslider

Using jQuery BxSlider 4.1.2 with the easing option break the slider in IE9 and lower :

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'ease-in-out'

Here is the setup I use:

```
jQuery('#cja_slider .bxslider').bxSlider({
      pager: false,
      speed: 1000,
      easing: 'ease-in-out',
      adaptiveHeight: true,
      auto: (jQuery('.bxslider li').size() > 1)
});
```

I'um using jQuery 1.10.4 so I can't use browser detection anymore to disable easing on IE9. Is there any work around for that issue?

Here is a fiddle that reproduce the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/vard/Luhx78x0/

Answer (score -1):

You want to use css3 transitions by default as they are hardware accelerated and much smoother.  I use Modernizr for feature detection and set the easing function depending on whether css3 animations are supported.  You could also use an easing library to get a better fit but I figure if you're still using IE9 you don't really care what websites look like anyway.

```
jQuery('#cja_slider .bxslider').bxSlider({
  pager: false,
  speed: 1000,
  easing: function() {
    return Modernizr.csstransitions ? "ease-in-out" : "linear";
  },
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  auto: (jQuery('.bxslider li').size() > 1)
});
```

Comment: Just as a note, I'm not using IE9, but still a lot of people does. And, sadly, I'm not making websites just for myself.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to replace the easing function with the single line: *'easing': Modernizr.csstransitions ? 'ease' : 'swing',*